# Need to capture images inside the rectangular view using camera in android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

Am creating a document scanning application in android, am using OpenCV and Scan library in my project for cropping,I have created a rectangle using drawrect in camera view, now I need to capture the images inside that rectangle portion only and display it in another activity.

The image in question:

[image]

Comment: u can take the normal image from the camera and later draw it in a canvas crop the part that are in outer rectangle

Comment: @Preethi Rao but actually I need to pass the image inside the rectangular view how I can pass that image portion only

Comment: i dont know purpose of passing image inside rectangular view from the image what i saw u can draw a rectangle over the canvas and draw image in the same canvas and crop unwanted portions

Comment: but how do I know which part of the image is inside the rectangular portion, then only I can pass it nah, hope u understood

Comment: post your bitmap area code

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav Can you explain / show how you did it ?

Comment: @M Balajivaishnav, i am also trying document scanner what you did it. Could you please share the code?..

Comment: @user what you actually trying to do ?

Comment: i need to scan the document, while open surfaceview(camera) i need to display with frame with size of a4 sheet, and take picture and crop the image automatically the size of as sheet.

Comment: are you trying auto capture of document ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me , I will take whole image, then crop.
Your question : "how do I know which part of the image is inside the rectangular portion, then only I can pass it nah, hope u understood". My answer is you can using relativity scaling of whole image dimension and camera display screen dimension. Then you will know which part of rectangular to be cropped.

This is the code example.
Note that you need to fill some codes to make it can save file into jpg, and save it after cropped.

```
    // 1. Save your bitmap to file
    public class MyPictureCallback implements Camera.PictureCallback  {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        try {
            //mPictureFile is a file to save the captured image
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }

    // Somewhere in your code
    // 2.1 Load bitmap from your .jpg file              
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+"/mPictureFile_name.jpg");

    // 2.2 Rotate the bitmap to be the same as display, if need.
    ... Add some bitmap rotate code

    // 2.3 Size of rotated bitmap
    int bitWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bitHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    // 3. Size of camera preview on screen  
    int preWidth = preview.getWidth();
    int preHeight = preview.getHeight();

    // 4. Scale it. 
    // Assume you draw Rect as "canvas.drawRect(60, 50, 210, 297, paint);" command
    int startx = 60 * bitWidth / preWidth;
    int starty = 50 * bitHeight / preHeight;
    int endx = 210 * bitWidth / preWidth;
    int endy = 297 * bitHeight / preHeight;

    // 5. Crop image
    Bitmap blueArea = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, startx, starty, endx, endy);

    // 6. Save Crop bitmap to file
```

Comment: can u give me some link or code snippet to undersatnd

Comment: @M Balajivaishnav . Show me your code to draw rectangular on the camara view. I will add the necessary part to make it work.

Comment: can I paste it in paste bin link

Comment: do u know the solution for it

Comment: can u tell me what is preview I think its not declared any where

Comment: preview is defined in your code. I use it to get size in pixel of your surfaceview -- > preview = new Preview(this,(SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.KutCameraFragment));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107912/discussion-between---and-m-balajivaishnav).

Comment: Finally worked after changing some codes, thank you your code made me to understand the logic behind it

Comment: @ปรีดาตั้งนภากร do u know how to crop exact images after capturing it, like cam scanner, office lens application are doing it, have any idea on that

Comment: @M Balajivaishnav. No, I do not.

Comment: @balajivaishnav did you found any exact solution for this? I mean clicking pics like cam scanner?

Comment: Yes I have sorted it out

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you: [How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android)

Make sure that the view (v1 in the code sample's case) passed in Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache()) is a viewgroup that contains the image you want ot send to the second activity

Edit: 
I don't think your intended flow is feasible.  As far as I know, camera intents don't take arguments allowing to draw such a rectangle (I could be wrong though).

Instead, I suggest you take a picture, and then edit it with a library such as this one (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) or programatically as suggested above.

Comment: taking screen shot huh ? but I need to capture from the camera, please see the link

Comment: It will take 2 steps instead of 1 step, so I think it is not good for UX